# AS3, dynamic conversion from String to datatype x

Tags: actionscript-3, type-conversion

is there a way to convert dynamicly?

that's the default way to convert a String:

var toVal:* = int("5");
var toVal:* = Boolean("true");

but I wan't to do this:

var type:String = "int";
var toVal:* = type("5");  // <<<<< how can I do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try one of:

```
var type:Class = int;
// or
var type:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName("int") as Class;

var toVal:* = type("5");
```

Example program:

```
var test:* = "5";

var type:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName("int") as Class;

var toVal:* = type("5");

if(test is String) {
    trace("Test is a string"); // traces
}

if(test is int) {
    trace("Test is an int"); // ignored
}

if(toVal is String) {
    trace("toVal is a string"); // ignored
}

if(toVal is int) {
    trace("toVal is an int"); // traces
}
```

Comment: I think you have to cast it as a `Class` to assign it to a strongly typed variable like that. `var type:Class = Class(int)`, but other than that it should work.